# Select/Deselect checkbox does not work after selectAll checkbox clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a jquery datatable. One of its column consists of checkboxes as you can see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7v5oevvdrxhb7qf/Screenshot%202015-09-02%2010.57.03.png?dl=0) . Now, when I click the checkboxes on the rows they work fine. I mean it prints out ***one of the single select class checkbox is checked*** or ***one of the single select class checkbox is unchecked***, since I added these on the event handler. However, if I click select all once, my individual checkboxes does not run anymore (it does not print out these messages).Select all checkboxes look like work fine. (selects all individual boxes). Here is my select all and single select checkbox related code :

**SelectAll handler :**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][id="selectAll"]').click(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        converter.checkAll(true);

    } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        converter.checkAll(false);
    }
});
```

**checkAll function**

```
Converter.prototype.checkAll = function (checktoggle) {
    var data = (this.resultTable).fnGetData();
    for (var i in data) {
        var row = $('<div>' + data[i][3] + '</div> ');

        row.children('input').attr('checked', (checktoggle) ? 'checked' : false);
        row.children('input').attr('id', 'singleSelect');
        console.log(row.html());

        (this.resultTable).fnUpdate(row.html(), parseInt(i, 10), 3, false, false);
    }
    (this.resultTable).fnDraw();
}
```

**Single Select Handler**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][id="singleSelect"]').click(function () {

    alert("asdasdasdasd");
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        alert('one of the single select class checkbox is checked');
    } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {

        alert('one of the single select class checkbox is unchecked');
    }
});
```

Comment: can you provide the html or better a fiddle

Comment: What is `converter` ?

Comment: @guest271314 converter is initialized to 'this' keyword inside one of Converter.prototype function

Comment: @JSantosh my project is too big and consist of several dependend projects so I dont know how to provide a fiddle with sych a project

Comment: @zwlayer _"converter is initialized to 'this' keyword inside one of Converter.prototype function"_ Is `this` same at both `converter.checkAll(true);` , `var data = (this.resultTable).fnGetData();` ?

Comment: @guest271314 `Converter.prototype.getResult = function() { converter=this; ....} `

Answer (score 0):

Use this mode

**SelectAll handler :**

```
// note change event
$('input[type="checkbox"][id="selectAll"]').change(function () {
        converter.checkAll($(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

**checkAll function**

```
Converter.prototype.checkAll = function (checktoggle) {
    var data = (this.resultTable).fnGetData();
    for (var i in data) {
        var row = $('<div>' + data[i][3] + '</div> ');

        row.children('input').prop('checked', checktoggle) ;
        row.children('input').attr('id', 'singleSelect');
        console.log(row.html());

        (this.resultTable).fnUpdate(row.html(), parseInt(i, 10), 3, false, false);
    }
    (this.resultTable).fnDraw();
}
```

**Single Select Handler**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][id="singleSelect"]').change(function () {

    alert("asdasdasdasd");
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        alert('one of the single select class checkbox is checked');
    } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {

        alert('one of the single select class checkbox is unchecked');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry if there is a typo mistake, I'm in mobile now

Comment: Thanks for reply, I replaced my code with yours, but it did not work. Now, select all does not even selects individual checkboxes

Comment: So share your html because there are things that I can't see by a crystal ball

Answer (score 0):

The issue appear to be

`$('input[type="checkbox"][id="selectAll"]').click(function () {`

is called on `input` with selector `[id="selectAll"]` ; `js` at post does not uncheck all checkboxes , but creates new `input` elements where `checked` attribute is set with argument `checktoggle`

---

> so what should I do in order to fix this issue ?

Difficult to confirm without `html` included at Question . Try utilizing `.each()` , setting `this.checked` to `true` , `false` within callback

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][id="selectAll"]').click(function (e) {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    if ($(e.target).prop("checked") == true) {
        this.checked = true;
        converter.checkAll(true);

    } else  {
        this.checked = false;
        converter.checkAll(false);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: is there anyway to change state of it between checked/unchecked rather than creating new checkboxes each time ?

Comment: @zwlayer _"is there anyway to change state of it between checked/unchecked rather than creating new checkboxes each time ?"_ Not entirely certain what expected result is ? Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? See updated post , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

We can make check/uncheck jQuery datatable by using checkbox names of child rows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#chkAll").click(function () {
            $("input[name='employees']").attr("checked", this.checked);
        });
        $('#example').DataTable({
        });
    });
</script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="left"><input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" /></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employees" /></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employees" /></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>

                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>
```

it works fine for more details http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-check-all-rows-in-jQuery-datatables-grid/1255